# Slay the Spire Default Mod Base: Game Crashed When Trying to Play as The Default

Tags: java

I'm following the [Default Mod Base](https://github.com/Alchyr/StS-DefaultModBase) tutorial and I stumbled on a problem. The game crashed when I try to start a new run as the Default:

```
Game crashed.
Version Info:
 - Java version (1.8.0_312)
 - Slay the Spire (12-22-2020)
 - ModTheSpire (3.23.4)
Mod list:
 - basemod (5.35.1)
 - stslib (1.24.1)
 - TestMod (0.0.1)

Cause:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.megacrit.cardcrawl.characters.AbstractPlayer.initializeStarterDeck(AbstractPlayer.java:450)
    at com.megacrit.cardcrawl.dungeons.AbstractDungeon.<init>(AbstractDungeon.java:362)
    at com.megacrit.cardcrawl.dungeons.Exordium.<init>(Exordium.java:50)
    at com.megacrit.cardcrawl.core.CardCrawlGame.getDungeon(CardCrawlGame.java:1379)
    at com.megacrit.cardcrawl.core.CardCrawlGame.update(CardCrawlGame.java:861)
    at com.megacrit.cardcrawl.core.CardCrawlGame.render(CardCrawlGame.java:419)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:225)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:126)Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:51595', transport: 'socket'
Setting breakpad minidump AppID = 646570
Steam_SetMinidumpSteamID:  Caching Steam ID:  -cut for privacy sake- [API loaded no]
```

Because of this, I used BaseMod's debug console to see if I can manually add the cards, relics, potions etc.

The things from the DefaultMod that work:

- All 4 relics
- The potion *(The GitHub page stated the mod has 1 character specific potion and 1 non-character specific potion, but I see only the non-character specific potion in the potion json file)*
- None of the powers
- Not sure how to add/test orbs
- The event
- And none of the cards

Also, these messages showed up when debugging ModTheSpire through IntelliJ.

This one is during the ModTheSpire mod selection window:

```
src\clientdll\steamclient.cpp (397) : Couldn't fit all the environmental variables in allotted space
subbed items: 7
result: OK
numResultsReturned: 7
totalMatchingResults: 7
isCachedData: false
Setting breakpad minidump AppID = 646570
Steam_SetMinidumpSteamID:  Caching Steam ID:  -cut for privacy sake- [API loaded no]
```

And this one is during the patching process (I think?), it's a window that shows what ModTheSpire has logged to the console before starting the game:

```
[Thread-5] WARN io.sentry.DefaultSentryClientFactory - No 'stacktrace.app.packages' was configured, this option is highly recommended as it affects stacktrace grouping and display on Sentry. See documentation: https://docs.sentry.io/clients/java/config/#in-application-stack-frames
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the people over at the [official Slay the Spire Discord](https://discord.com/invite/slaythespire) for the help.

For others who are experiencing the same issue, go to line 439 in DefaultMod.java

```
           And change this to "YourModID"
                       V
new AutoAdd("${project.artifactId}") // ${project.artifactId}
```

The comments on this part were a bit misleading, I thought I have to change it from "DefaultMod" to "${project.artifactId}".

And the other 2 warning messages are normal behavior, they can be ignored.